# refresh DOM after append element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#main_body').append("<h1>Hello</h1><input id=\"but\" type=\"button\">Click");
      $("#but").on("click", function() {
        alert("bla bla");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body id="main_body"></body>

</html>
```

Why alert doesn't work after append DOM? Should shows "bla bla" after click on it.

**SOLVED**

Main problem was with it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jquery was too old I think

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

solved problem :)

Comment: If you solved your question, you should add an answer. Your question is no longer a question and therefore is useless now!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is no longer a question. Op has deleted all the question and replaced with his answer

Answer (score 35):

For dynamically added elements you need event delegation, use the other version on jQuery [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/), you can delegate event to static parent of the dynamically added elements. In your case you can use `#main_body`

```
$('#main_body').on( "click", "#but", function() {
    alert( "bla bla" );
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Your code works [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/6hT9U/1/) as it is because you are adding the dynamically element before binding the event but using event delegation will free you from the sequence you use to add the dynamic elements.

Comment: Problem was with it:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

jquery was too old I think

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

solved problem :)

Comment: Fabulous answer.  Works great for me.

Answer (score 18):

You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically added element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main_body').append("<h1>Hello</h1><input id=\"but\" type=\"button\">Click");
    $('#main_body').on('click', '#but', function() {
        alert( "bla bla" );
    });
});
```

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future

Answer (score 7):

Use like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#main_body').append("<h1>Hello</h1><input id=\"but\" type=\"button\">Click");
        $(document).on("click", "#but", function () {
            alert("bla bla");
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body id="main_body">
</body>
```

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

It helps you to attach handlers for the dynamically created elements

Comment: Problem was with it:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

jquery was too old I think

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

solved problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You code should work

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6hT9U/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main_body').append("<h1>Hello</h1><input id=\"but\" type=\"button\">Click");
    $("#but").on("click", function () { //element is in DOM now as it added in previous statement
        alert("bla bla");
    });
});
```

Comment: Problem was with it:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

jquery was too old I think

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

solved problem :)

Comment: @user3345547 Glad you found the solution :).Your code was correct as i pointed in my answer . :)

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#main_body').append("something").ready(() => {
  $('#but').click(() => {
  }) 
});
```

Comment: Answers without explanation are downvoted more often than those with just code. Also `.ready`, no matter what it's called on, is always the same as `$(document).ready`. In other words, it's not solving any problems here that the OP's code (updated to a more recent version of jQuery) doesn't already do.

Comment: I am having the same issues back then. I wasnt able to call elements that are just appended recently. So i found out that after appending and after the dom is loaded that is the time u can call them. Atleast for me.