# load twitter profile on input change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter

I have a section in my app where user provide twitter account via input, now I want to display the profile on input change.

Here is Twitter docs on how to display embedded Twitter profile, https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview

Here is my live demo on jsfiddle :

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eg7jwy0r/2/)

Here is my solution: HTML

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>    
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="tw-containeritter">
         <a class="twitter-timeline" href="" data-tweet-limit="1"></a>
      </div>
      <input id="twitterurl" placeholder="provide the twitter url" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is js

```
$("#twitterurl").on('change', function(e) {

    var twitterUrl = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr('href', twitterUrl);

    setTimeout(function() {

        console.log("setTimeout twitter");
        twttr.widgets.load();
    }, 2000);
})
```

Now when the user provides the profile URL, the profile is not displayed

What do I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by 'I want to display the profile'?

Comment: Poltorin Twitter profile provided by user

Comment: still dont understand. Do you need a redirect to this profile? Or do you need specific account data?

Comment: Poltorin, I just want display Twitter profile using Twitter timeline, (embedded Twitter profile) here is docs https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I'm not an expert in JQuery, but I made it work. I found that for updating DOM you should use event delegetion. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373630/refresh-dom-after-append-element)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>    
   </head>
   <body id="main">
      <div class="tw-containeritter"></div>
      <input id="twitterurl" placeholder="provide the twitter url" />
   </body>
</html>


$("#main").on('input', '#twitterurl', function(e) {
    var twitterUrl = $(this).val();
    $('.tw-containeritter').append("<a class='twitter-timeline' href='' data-tweet-limit='1'></a>");
    $('.twitter-timeline').attr('href', twitterUrl);
    $('#twitterurl').blur();

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("setTimeout twitter");
        twttr.widgets.load();
    }, 2000);
})
```