# 2 Recaptcha same page different Forms

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

I need 2 recaptcha for 2 different forms. I have one and i cloned it for the other form the problem is that, now if i refresh to get another code the recaptcha will no longer recognise it. There is any other way to use 2 recaptcha without cloning?

I need one recaptcha for comment section and one for ordering a product and they are in different forms.

Comment: I personally recommend you to use the secureimage open source captch

Comment: if it wasn't so complicated to implement and require so many files i would.

Comment: Trust me its not i have used it myself

Comment: I will give it a go and see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show multiple recaptchas on a single page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241947/how-do-i-show-multiple-recaptchas-on-a-single-page)