# How can I clone a reCAPTCHA?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I am using two forms on a single page on a client's WordPress site. A while back I implemented reCAPTCHAs for each form. If I remember correctly you weren't able to use two on a single page so after doing some research I found that it could be done by cloning the first one with javascript.

```
<div id='ppc-recap'>
...(reCAPTCHA HTML removed for brevity)...
</div>

<div id='ppc-recap2'></div>

jQuery('#ppc-recap2').html(jQuery('#ppc-recap').clone(true,true));
```

This worked back then however now it is not. I get the following warning in the browser console:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

There are two of these warnings. Each appears to caused by the clones of the two scripts reCAPTCHA uses. I'm lost here, guys.

Comment: I draw captcha inside the form which has focus. Will that work?

Comment: Hmmm... that might work. How would I determine which form they are filling out?

Comment: I trap the focus event; in fact, I display when they start filling in the form. You can change it to mouseover/out. Not sure about usability though.

Comment: But what if they started filling out one then realized they should be filling out the other?

Comment: The captcha moves below the other one automatically. There will still be one captcha (the documentation suggests only one can be displayed).

Comment: Oh! I get it. Let me give that a try. Do you want to put that as an answer so I can mark it accepted once it works for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show multiple recaptchas on a single page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241947/how-do-i-show-multiple-recaptchas-on-a-single-page)