# How to have multiple forms using recaptcha on one page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, recaptcha

thanks for reading. My problem is that I have multiple tabs, each containing a form, which I was  hoping each to also contain a recaptcha. The problem is only the first recaptcha is displayed. You can see what I mean on [this page](http://mediareviewzone.com/review.php).

Another solution, which I am not too sure how to do, could be to have 1 recaptcha used by each form as only one form can be submitted at a time but the form would need to be split to have the recaptcha before the submit button.

Any help on either solution would be much appreciated (and also stop me from pulling my hair out). Thank you for your time.

Sorry if I did not give enough detail. Here is the end of one of the forms. They are all pretty much the same for this point.

```
<div class="row-textarea"><div class = "label">Review: </div>
  <textarea id="msg" name="content"  required></textarea>
</div>


<div class="captcha">
<?php
     require_once('HIDDEN/recaptchalib.php');
     $publickey = "HIDDEN";
     echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
</div>

<button class ="button" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

What would be ideal is to remove the captcha div from the form but still have it before the submit button.

Just thinking, the submit button is the same for all the forms too. Would there be a way for the tabs to change all of the form before the captcha and leave everything after the same to complete the form. That gives me something to ponder.

Comment: You need to post code.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28126317/531524

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show multiple recaptchas on a single page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241947/how-do-i-show-multiple-recaptchas-on-a-single-page)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the result I wanted by the method that I mentioned in my last edit. If anyone else has this problem (which they probably won't) how I fixed it was to only use one recaptcha located after the forms and then use positioning to position the submit button after the recaptcha.

Pretty simple now that I think about it. Sorry for wasting all your time, I am still quite new to web design and this seems like a rookie problem. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for anyone reading this for a solution but the previous solution did not work either. The recaptcha needs to be in the form. I also have a word counter that can also only work for one form. So my solution for this was to create links to a page which loads a single form depending on the link chosen. Not what I would have liked but it does the job.