# Reset Multiple Google reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I have two forms on a single page which both use Google reCAPTCHA.

Whenever i use `grecaptcha.reset();` it only resets the first instance.

The following JS renders the reCAPTCHA(s)

```
var recaptcha1;
var recaptcha2;

var myCallBack = function() {
    //Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
    recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
        'sitekey' : '1234', //Replace this with your Site key
        'theme' : 'light'
    });

    //Render the recaptcha2 on the element with ID "recaptcha2"
    recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
        'sitekey' : '1234', //Replace this with your Site key
        'theme' : 'light'
    });
};
```

How can i reset all instances or target a specific instance.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by mbejda is almost correct but not quite.

Through trial and error, I found that you have to do this:

```
grecaptcha.reset(recaptcha1);
grecaptcha.reset(recaptcha2);
```

To be clear, you have to save the return values of grecaptcha.render(), and pass in those vars to the reset() function. Passing in the string ID of the captcha doesn't work.

Comment: Additionally, if you log return values, they end up being 0, 1, 2, etc. For my use case, where the above was not possible due to restrictions out of my control, it was sufficient to just run the following: `grecaptcha.reset(0); grecaptcha.reset(1);`

Answer (score 4):

```
grecaptcha.reset(0);
grecaptcha.reset(1);
```

Answer (score 4):

A more dynamic approach to iterate over the captcha controls regardless of how many they are and reset them all. (using jQuery):

```js
    var c = $('.g-recaptcha').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < c; i++)
        grecaptcha.reset(i);
```

Comment: Just to put in my two cents, if by any means one of the existing ReCaptchas is removed, (e.g. if a form is posted via Ajax and removed from the DOM) then this solution gets invalidated, because it seems that the Captchas somehow remember their ID. So, I stored the initial g-recaptcha length, and always iterated that one when I needed to reset my captchas. Keep in mind that no error is thrown if you pass a previously existing ID.

Answer (score 1):

According to googles documentation here.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_param
You should be able to pass the captcha Id into the reset method. 
`grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);`

**So then you can do :**

```
    grecaptcha.reset("recaptcha1");
    grecaptcha.reset("recaptcha2");
```