# multiple recaptchas on one page

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

First of all, I found this approach here: [How do I show multiple recaptchas on a single page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241947/how-do-i-show-multiple-recaptchas-on-a-single-page/28126317#28126317)

I tried to use the same method like mentioned here, but that didn't do the trick. In my case, I'm using a typo3-instance, which has to have multiple (2) recaptchas on the same page.

Like mentioned in the answer above, I have a link like this in my `<head>`

```
<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explic‌​it" async defer></script>
```

Then comes the tricky part and I guess, this is where I am stuck:

I tried using the advised JS-snippet, but that didn't do anything. I put the JS-code in a js-file, as well as in my template, to see if the location causes troubles. However, nothing worked.

This is the JS-code i'm using (now taken from the template-file)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var CaptchaCallback = function () {
    console.log("arrived");
    $('.g-recaptcha').each(function (index, el) {
        grecaptcha.render(el, {'sitekey': 'my-key'});
    });
};
```

And this is how I try to disply my recaptchas:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{settings.recaptcha.sitekey}" id="recaptcha_{field.uid}"></div>
```

which ends up beeing something like this:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="abc-" id="recaptcha_21"></div>
```

No errors in my js-console as well...

Any ideas?

Comment: You need multiple script tags with a call back for each. You can add as many reCaptcha's as you need. See the docs: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display