# Invisible reCAPTCHA sending empty g-recaptcha-response with multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am trying to use [Google Invisible reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible), but it is sending empty the `g-recaptcha-response` POST parameter when i have multiple forms in the same page. Here is my code:

**Google JS**

```
<script src="//google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=pt-BR&onload=captchaCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

**Form 1**

```
<form action="/site/Contact/send" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="nome" required>

    <div class="g-recaptcha"
        data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        data-callback="form1Callback"
        data-size="invisible">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

**Form 2**

```
<form action="/site/Contact/send" id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="nome" required>

    <div class="g-recaptcha"
        data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        data-callback="form2Callback"
        data-size="invisible">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**My JS** (Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241947/how-do-i-show-multiple-recaptchas-on-a-single-page/33535769#33535769)]

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    window.captchaCallback = function(){
        $('.g-recaptcha').each(function(index, el) {
            var attributes = {
                'sitekey'  : $(el).data('sitekey'),
                'size'     : $(el).data('size'),
                'callback' : $(el).data('callback')
            };

            grecaptcha.render(el, attributes);
        });
    };

    window.form1Callback = function(){
         $('#form1').submit();
    };

    window.form2Callback = function(){
         $('#form2').submit();
    };
});
```

When i submit one of these forms the `g-recaptcha-response` parameter is sent empty, as below.

[image]

Can someone help me to put it to work, please?

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, please mark it as your accepted answer. That way the rest of the world knows which solution works in your particular situation.

Comment: @Aram, You are right, but none of the answers solved the issue, i am using single forms per page at this moment

Answer (score 6):

You will need to manually call grecaptcha.execute() to run recaptcha if you are rendering invisible recaptcha in a div element. Also if there are multiple forms with recaptcha, then the grecaptcha.execute() method needs to be called with a widget ID generated for each recaptcha when the grecaptcha.render() method is called.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.captchaCallback = function(){
        $('.g-recaptcha').each(function(index, el) {
            var attributes = {
                'sitekey'  : $(el).data('sitekey'),
                'size'     : $(el).data('size'),
                'callback' : $(el).data('callback')
            };

            $(el).data('recaptcha-widget-id', grecaptcha.render(el, attributes));
        });
    };

    window.form1Callback = function(){
        $('#form1').data("recaptcha-verified", true).submit();
    };

    window.form2Callback = function(){
        $('#form2').data("recaptcha-verified", true).submit();
    };

    $('#form1,#form2').on("submit", function(e){
        var $form = $(this);
        if ($form.data("recaptcha-verified")) return;

        e.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.execute($form.find(".g-recaptcha").data("recaptcha-widget-id"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation and your code I could guess you are trying to use `Programmatically invoke the challenge.` from [Google reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible).
So in your JS-code you missed one statements:

`grecaptcha.execute();`

**UPDATE**
Maybe I misunderstood you question, so check this:

> render    explicit onload Optional.  Whether to render the widget
>   explicitly. Defaults to onload, which will render the widget in the
>   first g-recaptcha tag it finds.

As I understood it's just found first marked tag and that causes you problem?

Comment: The default `onload` render the `g-recaptcha` only in the first tag it finds, because of this i changed to `explicit`, this way i can load in two elements