# validate google recapcha client side javascript

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm adding a recapcha v2 to a form. I've searched for how to validate the recapcha via Javascript client side to know if the recapcha has been completed before submitting the form. The form validates false regardless of whether or not the recapcha has been completed.

what I have tried:

```
      var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
      if(response.length == 0) 
      { 
        //reCaptcha not verified
        alert("please complete the reCAPCHA. Try Again!"); 
        
        return false;
      }
```

When I try to alert response, it's blank.  how do I get the code to know that the recapcha has been completed? The Javascript tests the other fields on the form fine.

I found another form on the site that uses:

```
if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == ""){
    alert("You must complete the recapcha in order to submit the form. Try again.");
    return false;
}
```

This form works as one would expect. I tried adding this validation to the form that does not and it keeps telling me to complete the recapcha even if I have.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 forms on the page that have been created in modal windows. They are all hidden until someone clicks the link to display the overlay window and thus the form. As a result, the same reCAPCHA is exists 3 times in the page code. When I call:

```
if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == ""){
    alert("You must complete the reCAPCHA in order to submit the form. Try again.");
    return false;
}
```

to check if the reCAPCHA has been completed, how does the code know which reCAPCHA to get the response of? Does it simply grab it from the one highest on the page? It’s not like it has a form reference. I checked and the form highest in the code functions as expected, the other 2 do not. The lower two return blank responses even if the reCAPCHA has been completed.
After a bit of research, I found the following question: [How do I show multiple recaptchas on a single page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241947/how-do-i-show-multiple-recaptchas-on-a-single-page) which states that: multiple forms on a single page must share the reCAPCHA.

Here is my solution:
I created a single modal window with 4 DIVs in it. Each DIV has the title and form fields in it. The DIVs get IDs form1 to form3 and reCAPCHA.  I then link to the form using javascript:displayForm(1 or 2 or 3). The function DisplayForm(id) takes the passed id and shows the corresponding form hiding the other 2.

```
function displayForm(id){
                if(id == 1){
                    document.getElementById('form1').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('form2').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('form3').style.display = "none";    
                    document.getElementById('which').value = 1;
                    document.location = "#popup3"
            }
            
            if(id == 2){
                document.getElementById('form1').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('form2').style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('form3').style.display = "none";    
                document.getElementById('which').value = 2;
                document.location = "#popup3"                   
            }
            
            if(id == 3){
                document.getElementById('form1').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('form2').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('form3').style.display = "block";   
                document.getElementById('which').value = 3;
                document.location = "#popup3"
            }
    }
```

This gives me the ability to show any of the 3 forms with one reCapcha.  I then had to add a hidden form field in the reCAPCHA DIV to indicate which form was displayed. This will allow the form validation Javascript to validate the correct form.

```
Function checkForms(id){
    If (id == 1){
        Check form 1
    } 
    If (id == 2){
        Check form 2
    }
    If (id == 3){
        Check form 3
    }
    Check reCAPCHA{
    }
}
```

I then have to combine the 3 form processing pages into one and pass the form id to the processing page so it knows which form to process.
The only good thing about all of this was that the forms are already built. It’s was a matter of stitching them all together in one modal popup and then eliminating the 3 separate ones. The small hiccup is that the 3 forms have fields with the same names which will have to be changed. This included the validation and on processing page.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26612846)

Comment: Yes it does. It states that there are 3 forms on the page each with the reCAPCHA and that that is not supported as the javascript does not get the response for the 2nd and 3rd form evwn if the reCAPCHA has been clicked. The only form that validates is the first. Therefore I am revuilding the form to work with only one reCAPCHA.

Comment: A problem I ran into was that having 3 separate forms now combined into one, some of the fields had the same name, functions for onFocus & onBlur. In total I had to change 14 field names, 2 onFocus functions, 2 onBlur functions and the processing page had to deal with the 14 fields that changed names.  This is where a spreadsheet came in handy to document all the changes at each step in the process: field, validation and processing. This is way more than a one day rewrite.

Comment: When I first looked, it appeared more like an idea of how one might think about solving the problem, than an actual definitive solution. It's a lot to read, & much speculation is included. Given the code in the question, it looks like you did give corresponding code mods to solve the problem. My apologies. I recommend a concise summary at the top, before going into the weeds & details of your entire thought process, to make this a bit more user friendly. Or nix the commentary. Add the found link (can't have >1 captcha) toward the top too. Give people the TLDR solution first. Upvotes may follow

Comment: I will edit it slightly when back in the office on Monday. It now works as i described.

Comment: The solution has been updated to better explain what I came up with. I tend to write my answers, stream of consciousness as I conceive them. It became a template for what I planned to build. Sometimes, I start posting a question and end up solving it before I finish it. Those never make it to the site.