# Validating multiple Captchas on a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I am building a comments section for a blog and I would really like some help\guidance with it, specifically around the Recaptcha. I have questions around

- Adding a variable amount of captchas to one page
- validating that the user has completed the captcha before posting to the server

A blog post can have X number of comments and for each comment left and I want to add a reply form for each. I've tried to mock this up in a .net fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/3GruG1) to demo it. In my application, the form is located in a partial, and when the foreach (blog comments) are processed it loads in a form at the bottom. The fiddle is purely for demo purposes and not how its implemented.

To try and limit spam submissions I would like to add a Recaptcha to each form. I've read that you can have multiple v2 Recaptcha per single view but can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this with a variable amount of forms per page? I am generating a GUID in the partial so maybe I can lean on that?

I assume this is achievable in js but my clientside is weak and before going down that route I wanted to get people's opinions on what is the best approach?

I would also like to validate that the user has interacted with the captcha - I played around with disabling the button until the box was checked but unsure if this is good for UX?

Any thoughts, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I show multiple recaptchas on a single page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241947/how-do-i-show-multiple-recaptchas-on-a-single-page)

Comment: I did stumble across this post and to be honest not really. It all feels a little static-like having a signup form and login form and hard coding id's etc. I need something a bit more dynamic. Also i need to validate the input clientside. Maybe i missed something though so ill re-read the post.. Thanks